# Converting to night build to use 3D in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, 3d, libgdx

I've reached a point in my program where I require the use of the LibGDX 3D engine, however from what I've read, the packages for it only come with the nightly build (including classes such as ModelInstance) and I've written my program using the standard LibGDX library.

Do I have to rewrite my program using the nightly build or is it possible to use a 3D engine with the standard library a different way / convert to nightly build in my existing project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3D api is included in the releases since 0.9.9. http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3239

Comment: Oh, I think I might be using 0.9.8, do you know how I could update to the newer version (while keeping my code)?

Comment: It depends on your setup, but you probably can just copy the new files over the old ones. http://libgdx.com/releases/ You'll have to update your code to meet API changes though, no way around that. Don't forget to make a backup upfront.